# understanding why future result with for comprehension yields Future[Nothing]

Tags: scala

Trying to understand why the following expression yields Future[Nothing] and not Future[List[Int]]

```
def foo(): Future[List[Int]] = Future(List(1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4))
def bar(): Future[Nothing] =for {
    fooList <- foo()
    f <- fooList.distinct
} yield f
```

of course, this is simplified example, and I can return the fooList directly. But I am trying to understand the reason of getting `Future[Nothing]` and not `Future[List[Int]]`

Comment: I get a type mismatch on the console, and that's what I expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I get a compiler error for your code, which is expected since `fooList.distinct` should have been a `Future` for the extractor `<-` to work on it.

```
scala> def foo() = Future(List(1,2,2,3))
foo: ()scala.concurrent.Future[List[Int]]


scala> for(fooList <- foo(); f <- fooList.distinct) yield f
<console>:17: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Int]
 required: scala.concurrent.Future[?]
              for(fooList <- foo(); f <- fooList.distinct) yield f
                                      ^
```

This code compiles:

```
scala> for(fooList <- foo(); f = fooList.distinct) yield f
res4: scala.concurrent.Future[List[Int]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@1e387e13
```

And this code also (wrapping the call to `distinct` into a Future):

```
scala> for(fooList <- foo(); f <- Future(fooList.distinct)) yield f
res5: scala.concurrent.Future[List[Int]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@623d211
res4: scala.concurrent.Future[List[Int]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@1e387e13
```

Comment: Thank you. (it is compile on the IDE , should have tried the repl )

Comment: This answer doesn't explain the reason why the approach of the OP is not valid.

Comment: @Haspemulator What about the first sentence? I could explain it in more depth. But maybe that's not always helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Scala's *for-comprehension* are just syntactic sugar for methods `flatMap`, `map` and `filter`. A code

```
for {
  x1 <- e1
  x2 =  e2
  x3 <- e3 if e4
  x4 <- e5
} yield e6
```

translates into (or something equivalent to)

```
e1.flatMap(x1 =>
e2.map(x2 =>
e3.filter(x3 => e4).flatMap(x3 =>
e5.map(x4 => e6)
```

The *for-comprehension* in your example becomes

```
foo().flatMap(fooList => fooList.distinct.map(f => f))
```

which is equivalent to

```
foo().flatMap(fooList => fooList.distinct)
```

because `map(id) = id` by definition of what a [Functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor) is. The method `foo().flatMap` takes an argument of type [`List[Int] ⇒ Future[S]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.concurrent.Future). But the function `fooList => fooList.distinct` is of type `List[Int] => List[Int]`. The compiler checks if the provided type is a subtype of the expected one. In your case the check falls to: *is* `List[Int]` *a subtype of* `Future[S]` *for some type* `S`. I'm not sure why the exepected type `S` is `Nothing` but it may be related to `Future` being covariant (as any `Functor` should).

Given a future of type `Future[T]`, `map` and `flatMap` both produce a `Future[S]` but the difference is:

- `map` takes arguments of type `T => S`. *Syntax* `x = ...` .
- `flatMap` takes arguments of type `T => Future[S]`. *Syntax* `x <- ...` .

The method you want is then `map` which gives

```
for (fooList <- foo())
yield fooList.distinct
```

or

```
foo().map(fooList => fooList.distinct)
```